# Automate connecting to database in OrientDB console

Tags: bash, console, automation, orientdb

I'm trying to automate my [OrientDB console](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Console-Commands) connecting. I've written a bash script,

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$(pwd)
cd ../libs/orientdb-community-1.7.4/bin
source console.sh "CONNECT remote:localhost/pumpup root pass"
```

But as soon as the commands in the console finish running, the console exits. Is there a way for me to automatically connect to my database with a script like this so I don't have to copy/paste my password?

Thanks

Comment: For us not knowing `console.sh`, can you it tell us what it does?

Comment: Sure, it runs the OrientDB console where you can connect to and modify your database. I've added a link in the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to send commands to the console via pipe. Example:

```
echo "CONNECT remote:localhost/pumpup root pass"|./console.sh
```

I've also tried:

```
./console.sh `echo "CONNECT remote:localhost/pumpup root pass"`
```

It executed the commands, but then exits because Java process finds the InputStream closed. I don't know if there is a way in Java to do it.

Comment: It looks like it runs the command, but the shell outputs a lot and it looks like it lags so much all I see is nothing. The only way to get out is CTRL+C.